# Notifying a customer via email when order status changed to shipped with BigCommerce API

Tags: email, status, bigcommerce

When you change the Order status to Shipped in BigCommerce, you can put in the Tracking ID and click on the check box that says "update the order status to Shipped, and notify the customer via email".  This works perfectly when I'm logged in an typing manually.

If however, I create a shipment using the BigCommerce API with CURL, I don't see any way to cause the customer notification email to be sent.  I have searched every place I can think of, and there doesn't seem to be anything in the API specifications or online help.  I can update shipped quantities and Tracking ID just fine.

Is there a way to also send the Shipped notification via email to the customer when using the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can create a shipment via API, that should update the order status to shipped or partially shipped which will trigger an email depending on store settings (listed under `Checkout` in the control panel).

[image]